# How to use variable in Textbox name in a loop?

Tags: excel, vba

In a `Do Until` loop, if I change
`TextBox69.Value` to `Controls("TextBox" & X).Value`, the loop gets interrupted.

It runs multiple times correctly when using the textbox but once I change it to the controls solution with a variable to replace the textbox number, *it only runs the entire loop one single time*.

```vb
Workbooks("Excel Stock System.xlsm").Worksheets("News Check").Controls("TextBox" & X).Value = _
  Workbooks("Excel Stock System.xlsm").Worksheets("DataNews_News").Cells(i, 4)
```

Here is the complete code

```vb
i = Workbooks("Excel Stock System.xlsm").Worksheets("DataNews_News").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Boxnumber = 14
X = 69

'This loops until all the lines are full
        
Do Until Boxnumber > 30 Or i < 4
    If Workbooks("Excel Stock System.xlsm").Worksheets("TESTSURFACE").Range("B29") = _
      Workbooks("Excel Stock System.xlsm").Worksheets("DataNews_News").Cells(i, 2) Then
            
        Workbooks("Excel Stock System.xlsm").Worksheets("News Check").Cells(Boxnumber, 3).Value = _
          Workbooks("Excel Stock System.xlsm").Worksheets("DataNews_News").Cells(i, 4)
            
        Workbooks("Excel Stock System.xlsm").Worksheets("News Check").Cells(Boxnumber, 2).Value = _
          Workbooks("Excel Stock System.xlsm").Worksheets("DataNews_News").Cells(i, 1)
            
        Boxnumber = Boxnumber + 1
        MsgBox ("does it just stop looping?" & Boxnumber)
            
        'why does this stop the loop from running in a loop??
        Workbooks("Excel Stock System.xlsm").Worksheets("News Check").Controls("TextBox" & X).Value = _
          Workbooks("Excel Stock System.xlsm").Worksheets("DataNews_News").Cells(i, 4)
        X = X + 1
    End If
    i = i - 1
Loop
```

Comment: Please do not post code in images. I would recommend delting the image and pasting the code.

Comment: Please also post the relevant section of the code. For example where are you setting the initial value of `X`?

Comment: Ive done that now. I could not figure out how code was displayed in here correctly earlier when posting this

Comment: I am guessing that the value of `i` becomes less than 4? Have you [Stepped](https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/debugging.html) through the code to see the value of each variables?

Comment: In your description, you refer to Textbox69, while in your code you have "TextBox" & X.  You have the "B" capitalized in the code, but not in your description.  This is important, as it is case sensitive.  Should it be "Textbox", or "TextBox"?

Comment: The thing is the loop runs perfectly if only i rewrite "Controls("textbox" & X).Value" to "textbox69.value", it all runs like it should except after adding the controls parts. It finds the search term correctly thus the i value actually stops at 18 where it finds the first hit, the box value also stops at the first hit. I intitally thought its a vba bug so i restarted excel but it did nothing to help, i had a problem once where excel simply had a bug but i guess this time its not it.

Comment: Oh sorry its "TextBox" with a big B the whole way. It does work for the first textbox, if this was the problem it would not fill out the first textbox..

Comment: Have you stepped through as Siddharth Rout suggested? We don't know anything about your set up.

Comment: Are they all the same kind of textbox? There's sheet, form and activeX controls and they don't work nicely together.

Comment: Yes ive stepped trough it. All the textboxes are exactly the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I refactored your code so it could take the advantage of defined variables which make it more readable and easier to debug.

A lot is going on in terms of variables changing their variables, so definetely looking at the locals window is a must

I couldn't make it work using the `Controls` collection, instead I used the `OLEObjects` (I don't know if I'm missing something about your setup)

```
Option Explicit

Sub LoopThroughTextBoxes()
    
    Dim stockSysWorkbook As Workbook
    Set stockSysWorkbook = ThisWorkbook 'Workbooks("Excel Stock System.xlsm")
    
    Dim dataNewsSheet As Worksheet
    Set dataNewsSheet = stockSysWorkbook.Worksheets("DataNews_News")
    
    Dim newsCheckSheet As Worksheet
    Set newsCheckSheet = stockSysWorkbook.Worksheets("News Check")
    
    Dim testSurfaceSheet As Worksheet
    Set testSurfaceSheet = stockSysWorkbook.Worksheets("TESTSURFACE")
    
    
    Dim boxNumber As Long
    boxNumber = 14
    
    Dim textBoxCounter As Long
    textBoxCounter = 69
    
    Dim rowNumber As Long
    rowNumber = dataNewsSheet.Cells(dataNewsSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    
    Do Until boxNumber > 30 Or rowNumber < 4
        
        If testSurfaceSheet.Range("B29").Value = dataNewsSheet.Cells(rowNumber, "B").Value Then
    
            newsCheckSheet.Cells(boxNumber, "C").Value = dataNewsSheet.Cells(rowNumber, "D").Value
            newsCheckSheet.Cells(boxNumber, "B").Value = dataNewsSheet.Cells(rowNumber, "A").Value
            
            boxNumber = boxNumber + 1
            
            Dim textObj As Object
            Set textObj = newsCheckSheet.OLEObjects("TextBox" & textBoxCounter).Object
                
            textObj.Value = dataNewsSheet.Cells(rowNumber, "D").Value
            
        End If
        
        rowNumber = rowNumber - 1
        
    Loop

End Sub
```

Let me know how it goes

PS. You have answers to your previous questions that were useful, so remember to mark them so others may find them too.

Comment: Thank you ! this helps me a lot. It works now and I figured out why I thought it worked with the first line: I had previously linked the textbox to a cell that it was also writing it into but I had forgotten about that. Clearly my fault but I just did not know any better and did not know the OLEObject function.